# Is there a way to dynamically control a table hint without using a dynamic sql query

Tags: sql-server, dynamic, hints

For example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[procGetTable]
    (
      @SetUPDLOCK BIT,
      @RecordId BigInt
    ) 
AS

SELECT * 
FROM MYTABLE WITH (CASE WHEN @SetUPDLOCK = 1 THEN 'UPDLOCK' ELSE '' END)
WHERE MYTABLE.RecordId = @RecordId
```

/* P.S. I Know the above does not work it conceptual only */

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[procGetTable]
      @SetUPDLOCK BIT,
      @RecordId BigInt
AS
BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON; 

    IF (@SetUPDLOCK = 1 )
      BEGIN
            SELECT * 
            FROM MYTABLE WITH (UPDLOCK)
            WHERE MYTABLE.RecordId = @RecordId
       END
    ELSE 
      BEGIN
            SELECT * 
            FROM MYTABLE
            WHERE MYTABLE.RecordId = @RecordId
       END
END
```

Comment: Cheers any way to do it without duplicating query statements

Comment: only other way is the dynamic sql then, here you are not duplicating the query only one of the queries will be executed.

Comment: Ok cheer I will make this one as the correct answer